# Crash on [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.data]

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, locking

I have this method with a crash on `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.data]`:

```
- (void) synchronize
{
    @synchronized (self.data)
    {
        NSData *encryptedData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.data] NL_AES256EncryptWithKey:userKey]; //La ça crash
        BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:encryptedData toFile:[self filename]];

        if (!success)
        {
            // we lost some data :(
            NSLog(@"Failed to synchronize to file %@", [self filename]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that all access to the object method (getter/setter) are protected with `@synchronized(self.data)` and this property is private.

Any idea?

**EDIT:** The crash log is explicit:

```
*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x1756a800> was mutated while being enumerated.

0   CoreFoundation  0x2e95becb __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x390f2ce7 objc_exception_throw + 39
2   CoreFoundation  0x2e95b9b9 -[NSException name] + 1
3   Foundation  0x2f2dd647 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 383
4   Foundation  0x2f2ddc2d -[NSArray(NSArray) encodeWithCoder:] + 189
5   Foundation  0x2f2dc479 _encodeObject + 1061
6   Foundation  0x2f2dd657 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 399
7   Foundation  0x2f2dd329 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 921
8   Foundation  0x2f2dc479 _encodeObject + 1061
9   Foundation  0x2f2e2899 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 157
```

But I don't know how to proceed to prevent the crash.

Comment: Are you using different thread to change the self.data?

Comment: Are you using Enumeration APIs anywhere in the code?? If your self.data is of Mutable data type and if you are using that with Enumeration APIs then it will cause this kind of crash. You cannot use both at a time.

Comment: @jailani: Yes: This class is a tool class used in my project to save data. But all methods of this class are called in different thread in all the code.

Comment: @DShah: No, i don't use the Enumeration API.

Comment: Allocate NSData and init with your self.data before archive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was due to enter a resource (self.data) for several different thread. 
My solution (which works) was this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t persistanceQueue;
```

On the init:

```
self.persistanceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.savingQueue", NULL);
```

For the sync method:

```
- (void) synchronize
{
    dispatch_sync(self.persistanceQueue, ^(void) {
        NSData *encryptedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.data];
        BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:encryptedData toFile:[self filename]];

        if (!success)
        {
            // we lost some data :(
            NSLog(@"Failed to synchronize to file %@", [self filename]);
        }
    });
}
```

For getters:

```
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)defaultName {
    __block id returnValue = nil;
    dispatch_sync(self.persistanceQueue, ^{
        returnValue = self.data[defaultName];
    });

    return returnValue;
}
```

And for Setters:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
{
    dispatch_sync(self.persistanceQueue, ^{
        if (value != nil)
            self.data[defaultName] = value;
        else
            NSLog(@"Failed to save %@", defaultName);
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe change the property from `assign` to `strong` is better.